# android update problems, button

Tags: android, android-button

My code was clean and ran great until I updated my `Eclipse IDE` to the new stuff. Sadly I went to compile some new code today and can't figure out the code changes.  Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have added 5 `Buttons` that I added with 5 sounds, I registered the sounds, added it all into it but it tells me I cannot add the `Buttons` into the application as it is older code and ADT 14 doesn't reference them in this manner.  It uses a Library project, but I have no folders for that on here or understand what it is asking.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you also update the Android SDK from the SDK Manager - if you haven't done that, Eclipse won't be very happy and Eclipse doesn't update the SDK for you.

Comment: I updated the sdk, the revision 14 is what the problem is and I want to rollback to 13.  Don't understand all the new changes right now and I would have to start from scratch to fix the app.

Comment: The changed the way to code the java file, not for sure how or why but that is the problem.

Comment: Since you say "tells me I cannot add the Buttons" - please post the stacktrace and/or LogCat.

Comment: I fixed the problem, I had two apps with the same name, but one had an extended name.  I edited app1's xml file but app2's java file.  I edited into the xml file and it all ran fine thanks.